# HTML-письма - как правильно подключить шрифты

Tags: html

Есть шрифт Bender - нужно подключить в верстку. Как правильно это сделать в html-письме?

Comment: спасибо. А Google так: `<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light);
/*  Место для формата css */
</style>`

Comment: При верстке писем смотрите [сюда](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: спасибо, да, знаю

Comment: поддержка для email - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> В почтовых рассылках допускается использование только стандартных
>   шрифтовых наборов, которые присутствуют на всех устройствах.
>   Представляю вашему вниманию список безопасных шрифтов, которые есть на
>   всех устройствах.
>
> ```
> font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
> font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
> font-family: Georgia, serif;
> font-family: 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
> font-family: 'MS Serif', 'New York', sans-serif;
> font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
> font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
> font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
> font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
> ```
>
> Таким образом, эти шрифты можно использовать в рассылках без страха и
>   риска. Если вы все же хотите использовать совсем нестандартные шрифты
>   через правило @font-face, то будьте внимательными, это правило
>   работает только в IOS, Google mail и Android 4 (Gmail).

[источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/)

**P.S:** вот такая конструкция в `head` позволяет гугл шрифты подключить, но за поддержку не скажу:

```
<!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
    <!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 9 - 26 can be safely removed. -->

    <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <!-- insert web font reference, eg: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!--<![endif]-->

  <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->
```

Еще вариант, вырезать текст и вставлять картинкой если это очень важно, но не рекомендуется из-за проблем с форматированием.

Comment: этак конструкция подключает все Google- шрифты или их нужно прописать дополнительно?

Comment: @Proshka, там же видно что только робото `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700'`

Comment: да, да, спешу, не замечаю. Спасибо