# Как вывести символ рубля в письме?

Tags: php, битрикс

Надо вывести символ рубля в письме. Как это правильно сделать? Насколько я понял сторонние шрифты в письма подключать нельзя. Есть юникодный символ, но говорят он на ios не отображается, а надо чтоб везде. Какие варианты?

P.S. Важный момент. Сайт на Битриксе и символ рубля везде берется из настроек валюты. Находил еще в интернете способ пихнуть svg, но в поле для валюты ограничена длина и его туда запихнуть не вышло - обрезался...

Comment: На иос не только отображатеся, но даже есть в стандартной клавиатуре - ₽.

Comment: png запихни и не парься

Answer (score 1):

Читал в прошлом году разбор этой проблемы с IOS. Она наблюдается только на некоторых шрифтах и в некоторых знаках валют (в т.ч. и рубли).

UPD нашел ссылку на разбор: https://habr.com/ru/company/livetyping/blog/312294/

Используйте для блока в который выводите переменную цены шрифт IOS у которого нет таких проблем, например Helvetica Neue или San Francisco.

> Насколько я понял сторонние шрифты в письма подключать нельзя.

Конечно можно: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/settings/settings/mail_events/message_edit.php

Используйте тело письма HTML и подключайте все что вам захочется через теги

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ещё возможное решение

Битрикс использует форматирование цен следующим образом:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/currency/functions/currencyformat.php

Вы можете убрать форматирование цены в письме. Оставить только само число (float), вывести его и после него через пробел добавить найденный вами SVG, PNG изображение и все что вам придет в голову.

Чтобы само число было не вида `11211.5`, а `11 211.5` или например `11 211,5` используйте number_format - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

```
$number = 1234.56

// английский формат (по умолчанию)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// французский формат
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56
```

UPD по универсальности.

Большинство почтовых сервисов будут работать с подключенными шрифтами с того же google fonts. Исключения составляют единичные случаи, например почтовые клиенты вроде outlook.

Вот список безопасных шрифтов, которые будут работать везде:

**Arial из этого списка поддерживает знак рубля.**

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-family: 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: 'MS Serif', 'New York', sans-serif;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

Своровано [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661494/html-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B)

Для того же outlook можно использовать специальные проверки в коде письма, например:

```
      <!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]-->
```

Вот здесь можно найти удобный список всего из CSS что работает, не работает в email верстке. Так, например, для outlook нужно делать табличную верстку, добавляя через проверки table туда, где используется блочная верстка.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Подключить то шрифт можно любой, но почтовые клиенты не будут его отображать...

Comment: Большинство почтовых клиентов работают с такими вещами. Исключения - всякие мертвые аутлуки, для которых можно написать свои проверки. 

Дополню ответ, спасибо.

Comment: @adudnik.ru насколько я знаю в письма в принципе нельзя подключать сторонние шрифты.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь (с оговорками). Обновил ответ. Посмотрите. Сам регулярно использую для более "красивой" верстке в письмах наборы из google fonts. В современном мире где у всех почта на сервисах вроде gmail, а так же в мобильниках аля андроид или IOS - это покрывает 100-99% получателей в web проектах (магазины, сайты и т.д.).

С стандартными шрифтами я бы работал только в гос. секторе или крупном корпоративном секторе аля гос. компании, где все жопой приросли к 2008 году.

Comment: В общем, если лень разбираться в том, что я писал - используйте в письме arial и знак рубля.

Comment: @adudnik.ru проверил. Ни один из этих шрифтов не отображает знак рубля в моем браузере. У меня windows 7 и chrome 79

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lowxta72/

Comment: http://anton-g-kulikov.github.io/rouble-test/

Comment: Если в вашем тесте не выводится символ через arial, тахому или гельветику - значит скопирован не верный знак. Просто возьмите его из ссылок что я вам отправил и вставьте куда нужно.

Comment: @adudnik.ru по первой ссылке я вижу только квадратик. Ну нету там символа рубля!!! Не отображается он: http://skrinshoter.ru/i/140120/fSCgJitX.png

Comment: А по второй в нижнем списке системных шрифтов?

Comment: @adudnik.ru у системных по второй тоже квадратики: http://skrinshoter.ru/i/140120/RmR1Yrqu.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103289/discussion-between-adudnik-ru-and-).

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй по юникоду `U+20BD`.
Насколько я знаю, он отображается в iOS.

Comment: Этот символ не отображается даже у меня в хроме на десктопе

Comment: Пробовал `&#x584;`, `&#8381;`, `&#x20bd;`. Из них только первый отображается как рубль. Остальные как квадратик

Comment: В принципе можно было бы использовать `&#x584;`, но проявилась еще странная проблема: символ отображается ниже чем цифра. Не знаю как их выравнять...